# Obtain MAC Address of Devices in range of router

Tags: iphone, c, networking, operating-system, router

Is it possible for a router to obtain the MAC address of nearby devices that have not connected to it? I want to write an app that notifies me somehow (email or something) when a specific MAC address comes within range of a router that I have (the app is much more specific than that so I cannot use prebuilt tools but if they are open source they could help). The router will be connected to the internet and the device is an iPhone so it is constantly looking for WiFi access points so I feel like all the ingredients are there but I am not sure if what I am asking is possible. If it is possible (even if only by rewriting the router OS) what will it take? C is as low level as I am hoping to go...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Linux-based router that you can program, which usually means one that runs OpenWRT or DD-WRT can do this; you can put the router in monitor mode, and have tcpdump or tshark listen for that particular MAC address.  If you want, you could write your own capture application that would use libpcap to listen.  If you can live with only scanning the active channel, the router could be providing an access point at the same time.

You could also listen to the logs of a standard router, but the issue there is that the phone would have to at least attempt association before the router would log anything; with a linux router, you can just listen for that MAC address emitting any packet at all.

My favourite Linux-based routers come from [Ubiquiti](http://www.ubnt.com), because their RouterStation Pro is built to run OpenWRT, so there is no hacking and complete hardware documentation.

Comment: I just noticed this response is something I have been looking for. I was wondering if you would have a script to add to a DDWRT device to make this happen? I would like to feed the MAC addresses seen by a DDWRT device into a database? Is this possible? Thanks Robert

Comment: @RenegadeRob Hey, I was wondering if you found any information on this topic? I'm searching for the exact same thing!

Comment: Hi @RansonNamba No I didnt. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the router. There are routers out there which have completely open operating systems, such as the Linksys WRT54GL, for which the OpenWRT, DD-WRT and Tomato operating systems exist.  You could (for example) develop a simple bash script to interpret the log files and email you.

You experience with other routers may vary.  Many have log files which are accessible via http or telnet, so you may be able to interpret this externally even if you can't run your own code on the router.

Comment: Hi @ColinPickard I was wondering if you had an example of the Bash script you mentioned to do this on a DDWRT device? I would like to feed the MAC addresses to a database? Thanks Robert

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing that by router you actually mean a wifi access point (which may be integrated into a home router) and you are talking about wifi connections. Then no, it is not possible. The access point only knows the MAC address when the device at least tried to connect to its network. The list of nearby networks that the device shows however does not require any form of connection to any of the networks. Instead, they listen for the beacons that the access points send out.

Comment: Devices also probe for networks, thus revealing their MAC address in the probe packets.  So you can listen for that, if the device is sufficiently programmable.

Comment: Thomas,
So you mean to say if devices are just in the range and not actually connected to the wireless router, it is impossible to program the router (OpenWRT) to know the MAC addresses of those devices? Appreciate your reply!