# Is there a way to see any device Information that is or was in range of my router

Tags: logging, wifi, device, router, history

I'm looking for a history log of any devices that were in the range of my router on a certain day. Is that possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general no.
There might be some router that logs it by default but most likely not.

Note that you can only see *active* devices, when they transmit something.

If you want to do it from now on it's pretty easy to see what active wi-fi devices *your computer* sees, there are many programs that let you do that (not all adapters support it though).

To know what your router sees, I don't know if there's any that has even options for that, most likely you'd have to change its firmware or modify it in some other way.

---

This question is closely related:
[obtain-mac-address-of-devices-in-range-of-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264929/obtain-mac-address-of-devices-in-range-of-router)

And these to a lesser extent
[find-mac-addresses-of-devices-in-range-of-wifi-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531124/find-mac-addresses-of-devices-in-range-of-wifi-router)
[wi-fi-client-mac-address-scanning](https://superuser.com/questions/471450/wi-fi-client-mac-address-scanning)